# Custom interceptors in coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I've been getting familiar with the `ContinuationInterceptor` section of coroutines
I wrote the following section of code to verify my idea

```
class MyContext: CoroutineContext.Element{
    override val key : CoroutineContext.Key<*>
    get() = object : CoroutineContext.Key<MyContext>{}
}

val myInterceptor = object : ContinuationInterceptor {
    //Key is set to a non-interceptor type
    override val key : CoroutineContext.Key<MyContext>
    get() = object : CoroutineContext.Key<MyContext>{}

    override fun <T> interceptContinuation(continuation: 
        Continuation<T>): Continuation<T> {
        Log.i(TAG,"interceptor:"+continuation.context[CoroutineName].toString())
        return Continuation(EmptyCoroutineContext) {
            thread(name = "myThread") {
                continuation.resumeWith(it)
            }
        }
    }
}

lifecycleScope.launch(myInterceptor + CoroutineName("MY1")) {
    Log.i(TAG,"MY1 start:"+Thread.currentThread().name)
    fun1()

    launch(CoroutineName("MY2")) {
        Log.i(TAG,"MY2 run:"+Thread.currentThread().name)
    }
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main+CoroutineName("MY3")) {
        Log.i(TAG,"MY3 run:"+Thread.currentThread().name)
    }
    Log.i(TAG,"MY1 end:"+Thread.currentThread().name)
}
```

[image]

I don't have the myInterceptor Key specified as `ContinuationInterceptor.Key`.

So coroutines should not recognize it as an Interceptor.

`MY1` and `MY2` prove this idea, but `MY3` is intercepted by `myInterceptor` and runs in a new thread.

I wonder:

1. Why is `myInterceptor` recognized as an interceptor
2. Why does not `Dispatcher.Main` work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of the shown code is weird. I couldn't find the exact reason why.

I fixed some obvious problems with your code, such as returning a new object from `key` every time, and not implementing `equals`. I return a singleton, so the default `equals` works:

```
class MyContext: CoroutineContext.Element {
    companion object Key : CoroutineContext.Key<MyContext>
    override val key: CoroutineContext.Key<MyContext> = Key
}

val myInterceptor = object : ContinuationInterceptor {
    override val key: CoroutineContext.Key<MyContext> = MyContext.Key

    override fun <T> interceptContinuation(continuation: Continuation<T>): Continuation<T> {
        println("interceptContinuation: ${continuation.context[CoroutineName]?.name}")
        return Continuation(EmptyCoroutineContext) {
            thread(name = "myThread") {
                continuation.resumeWith(it)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun toString() = "My Interceptor"
}
```

These fixes don't change the behavior, though, and we can see it's broken even before messing with the dispatching:

```
val goodCtx = CoroutineName("A") + CoroutineName("B")
val badCtx = myInterceptor + myInterceptor
println(goodCtx)
println(badCtx)
```

This prints

```
CoroutineName(B)
[My Interceptor, My Interceptor]
```

The first line shows you what the behavior is supposed to be, and the second one shows what it is with your implementation. You broke the equality relation. I didn't get to realizing why.

Even this finding doesn't directly explain how come your interceptor ends up being used, but it does give you some insight into what kind of things start happening when you use the framework against the intention of the authors.

Comment: LOL,I deliberately went against the intent of the framework,Perhaps time should not be wasted on such wrong behavior

Comment: Yes, it was quite clear that you were being deliberate about it. To some degree, I think such explorations are valid, and the behavior should make more sense. On the other hand, I bet the Kotlin Coroutines team has better ways to invest their time and effort than straightening out behaviors in cases they aren't interested in supporting.